# Factorization of a morphism of varieties over an open dense subset extends over entire variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, abelian-varieties

Let $X, Y, Z$ three $k$-varieties.
By "variety over field $k$" I mean a
separated $k$-scheme of finite type which
is geometrically integral.

Suppose that $f: X \to Z, g: X \to Y$ and
$h: Y \to Z$ are morphisms
and there is an open dense subvariety
$U \subset X$ such that the restriction
of $f$ to $U$ factorizes as
$f \circ rest(U)= h \circ g \circ rest(U)$ where
$rest(U): U \to X$ is the canonical open embedding.

Why this implies that then the morphism $f$
factorizes as $f= h \circ g$? Note that
$Y$ is not assumed to be proper therefore
the valuative criterion to force
$f$ factorize at every point $x \in X$ over $Y$
not works.
In the original text ([Abelian varities](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/elenalavanda/BMoonen.pdf), Lemma
1.11 ("Rigidity") uses that $X$ is irreducible.
Why this serves the implication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $i:W \to X$, as the base change of $\Delta: Z\to Z\times Z$ by  $(f ,h\circ g): X\to Z\times Z$.

Now $\Delta$ is a closed immersion (since $Z$ is seperated over $\operatorname{Spec} k$), implies $i:W\to X$ is a closed immersion.

Further, consider the scheme theoretic image $i(W)$ of $i$ in $X$, it is a closed subset of $X$ with scheme structure from that of $W$. On the other hand, since $X$ is reduced (hence $U$ is reduced), the scheme theoretic image $Im(j)$ of $j:  U\to X$ is $X$ itself. (see Exercise 3.11(d), Chapter 2, Hartshorne)

Since $j:U\to X$ factorizes through $W\to X$, the image schemes $i(W)$ and $X$ have the same underlying topological spaces and are isomorphic as schemes. (See Exercise 3.11(c), Chapter 2, Hartshorne and use sort of `universal property' of scheme theoretic image)

Thus, $f=h\circ g$ on $X$.

This is essentially the Exercise 4.2 Chapter II, Hartshorne.

Comment: Thank you, so the crucial input was that $Z$ is separable (this has the feature that $\Delta$ is closed immersion)?

Comment: @user7391733  Yes, that $Z$ is separated over Spec k.

Comment: You’re also using the fact that $X$ is reduced, no?

Comment: @Mindlack Absolutely, I should have stressed that earlier. I have incorporated the precise places where it is being used.